# Cursor do input indo para final da linha com jQuery e propertychange

Tags: javascript, jquery

Por exemplo, eu preencho o input [deste fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/claudiosw/c087se12/5/) com "ste" e depois volto para o início do input para digitar "te" antes de "ste", ele vai para o fim do input quando digito o primeiro caractere "t".
Ou seja, sempre que digito um caractere e o cursor não está no fim, o cursor vai para o fim do input após eu digitar o caractere.

Este é o script que estou utilizando. Vi em algum lugar que setando o this.selectionEnd funcionaria mas não funcionou.

```
    $('body').on('input propertychange', '#form_cliente_id', function (e) {
        var position = this.selectionStart;
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#form_cliente_id').submit();
        this.selectionEnd = position;
    });
```

Alguma dica de por que está acontecendo isso e como resolver?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que o problema estava no seguinte trecho:

```
oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()"
```

Retirando este trecho e incluindo este trecho, resolveu o problema:

```
style="text-transform: uppercase;"
```

Answer (score -1):

Você estava pondo o manipulador de evento no *id* errado. Em vez de `#form_cliente_id`, deveria ser `#nomecliente`:

```
$(function () {
  $(document).on('change', '#nomecliente', function () {
    alert('Submitei o form com nome de cliente: "' + $(this).val() + '"');
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
  });
});
```

Veja o [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzjLxq3s/2/).

Comment: #form_cliente_id é o id do form. O código original é ativado quando algo é mudado em qualquer input do form. No exemplo da pergunta não faz muita diferença, mas no caso real há vários inputs.
Além disso, o problema não foi corrigido em seu fiddle.
Mas acabei descobrindo a solução